# Inconsistency using printf

Tags: c, function, sqrt

I am using Code Block with GNU GCC Compiler. And I am trying this code

```
int number,temp;

printf("Enter a number :");
scanf("%d",&number);
temp = sqrt(number);
printf("\n%d",sqrt(number)); //print 987388755 -- > wrong result
printf("\n%d",temp); //print 3 -- > write result

return 0;
```

and in this code there are a result for input value 10 is

```
987388755  
3
```

what is wrong in this code?

Comment: You're using the GNU GNU C Compiler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sqrt` returns a double:

```
double sqrt(double x);
```

You need:

```
printf("\n%g",sqrt(number));
```

Answer (score 6):

Using incorrect format specifier in `printf()` invokes `Undefined Behaviour`. `sqrt()` returns double but you use `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
printf("\n%d",sqrt(number));
```

to:

```
printf("\n%g",sqrt(number));
```

Note that `sqrt()` returns a `double`, not an `int` - your compiler should be warning you about this, so long as you have warnings enabled. e.g. `gcc -Wall ...` (and if you don't have warnings enabled, then it's time to start making a habit of it).